# default_scope ActiveRecord 4.1 block usage for ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord 4.1 where some things changed on [default_scope](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#changes-on-default-scopes)  and my entire deploy fails because of this line:

default_scope order('pos ASC')

I have commented it out as of now, but how would you write this ordering in a block form? or is there a better way to sort results in a Model

The model looks like this:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name="THE_ANSWERS"
  self.primary_key="id"
  self.sequence_name = :autogenerated
  # -> default_scope order('pos ASC')

  belongs_to :question
end
```

I assume one can write `default_scope { where order: 'pos ASC'}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `default_scope` like this:

```
scope :ordered, ->{ order(pos: :asc) }
default_scope { ordered }
```

Or directly:

```
default_scope { order(pos: :asc) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending MrYoshiji's answer:

You can define the `default_scope` directly as:

```
default_scope { order(:pos) }
```

as by default ordering is always *ascending*.

The changes in `default_scope` for Rails 4.1 states that, the `default_scope` would be merged with all the other scopes defined in the model *on the same field*.

For example:

If you have something like this in your model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ##..
  default_scope { where pos: 1 } 
  scope :get_positions, ->(mypos) { where pos: mypos }
end
```

Then when you execute the following:

```
Answer.all
# SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."pos" = 1

Answer.get_positions(10)
# SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."pos" = 1 AND "answers"."pos" = 10
```

**Notice** `default_scope` is merged in the query for `get_positions` scope as they are *on the same fields (i.e., `pos`)* which never used to happen in the prior versions of Rails.

Comment: Hmmm, the `default_scope` is actually merged to my other scopes in Rails 3.2.13. I have to use `Model.unscoped` to skip this `default_scope`

Comment: I missed to add *on the same field*. Let me update my answer.